# Labview: How do I build an array of many copies of the same value?

Tags: arrays, labview

I'm using a MEAN function from the Prob and Stats function palette in one of my subVIs to attempt to counteract aliasing from a speed sensor.

I tried a butterworth filter, but it needs about 2000 samples at 2kHz to properly correct the aliasing, and that causes an instrumentation delay.

The problem is, the MEAN function takes a 1D array of about 800 elements and gives the mean.  I need to return it to a 1D array of 800 elements to be able to record and act on that data. I'm fairly certain that the "build Array" function only inserts the data into the array 1 element at a time though.

Is there any faster way to build a 1D array of 800 elements from the output of that MEAN function, or do I have to expand the "Build Array" funtion into a SubVI and copy it 800 times?  Thanks!!!

[image]

Comment: What you're trying to do is a little unclear to me. It sounds like you're starting with an 800 sample array and feeding that into Mean.vi where it gives you a single result; and then you want to put that result back into the array used to generate the mean. Am I tracking or way off?

Comment: @Dave_St I'm trying to build and fill an 800 element array of the mean.Vi output, instead of an 800 element array in which the mean.vi output is only the first element.

Comment: Each new mean will have to be inserted into the array so it'll have to be done 800 times. But you don't have to make 800 copies. You could use a loop with a shift register.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Initialize Array.vi`](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/glang/initialize_array/) from the [Array](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/glang/array_functions/) palette.

Wire the output from `Mean.vi` to the `element` terminal. Use the [`Array Size.vi`](https://zone.ni.com/reference/en-XX/help/371361J-01/glang/array_size/) on the original array and wire it to `dimension size 0`. This will guarantee that the resulting array will always match the original's size, in case you change your DAQ configuration.

[image: Initialize Array.vi]

Comment: Thanks! That worked perfectly! I didn't think to use the Initialize Array function. For some reason, in my head, it meant something different.